# is there a name for a language with very few roots?

Tags: terminology

It appears to me that German is a language whose vocabulary is strongly based on combining a few lexemes with a variety of prefixes, or just yuxtaposing. By contrast, romance languages seem to use far more "unique" roots. I wonder if such a distinction is made when classifying languages in some respect.

I'm no linguist and I can't find a way to ask the correct question or to phrase it so as to find the answer on my own with a Google search.

Comment: Romance with a capital r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A language that tends to build words through affixation or compounding is called an [agglutinative language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agglutinative_language).

The opposite, with a large number of distinct words and less compounding, is called an [isolating language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolating_language).

Note that many languages have elements of both.

Comment: Affixation is directly related to agglutinativity, but compounding is not. Many isolating or inflecting languages use compounding heavily, and it’s actually quite common for agglutinating, particularly polysynthetic, languages _not_ to make widespread use of at least endocentric compound nouns (the most common type of compound in Germanic languages). German, of course, is **not** an agglutinative language. It doesn’t make significantly more use of affixation (especially not prefixation, as mentioned in the question) than Romance languages, for example.